Mudblazor how to change MudNavGroup Font-weight
I want to change style of MudNavGroup element in MudNavMenu and just change font-weight.
<style>
.Boled{
font-weight:bold;
}

.mud-nav-link{
 font-size: x-small;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
</style>

this style only affects on MudNavLink element. I also tried out Style and Class attributes on the MudNavGroup element and it doesn't made any changes, and default style will not change.
<MudNavGroup Title="hello" Expanded="true"
                 Style="font-weight:700">

<MudNavGroup Title="hello" Expanded="true"
                 Class="Boled">

I also changed .mud-nav-link in style (may be get the result) but it  does not any effect on MudNavGroup too.
how can i change default style of these two elements MudNavGroup and MudNavLink and how to control style of MudNavGroup in expanded state and not expanded state.
any suggestion welcome.

You may need to override the css by providing your own.
The nav link is used as the display text for the nav group. Using the browser dev tools you can come up with the classes you need to reference for expanded and not expanded
Expanded - .mud-nav-group>.mud-nav-link.mud-expanded>.mud-nav-link-text
Closed - .mud-nav-group>.mud-nav-link>.mud-nav-link-text
<style>
    .mud-nav-group>.mud-nav-link>.mud-nav-link-text {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: red;
    }

    .mud-nav-group>.mud-nav-link.mud-expanded>.mud-nav-link-text {
        font-weight: 800;
        color: green;
    }
</style>

see https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuGelFFlSRZGEprr
